# Adding a new column is deleting all the existing columns of datagrid view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am using a datagridview in which I have added columns in designmode and it is not databound.This grid was working perfectly fine for a long time.Now I want to insert a new column to the datagrid view,and I am not able to add the column.If I am adding it is deleting all the existing columns of datagridview.I am not even able to edit the existing columns as the same thing is happening(Deletion of all the columns of datagrid view).I have googled so much and couldn't find a possible solution.If anyone has experienced the same issue kindly provide a solution.
note:Am not adding any rows or columns programatically.Its a windows application using c# .net vs2010.

thanks

Comment: Please provide a few lines of code showing how you are adding the new column.

Comment: I am not writing any code.am just adding it by clicking on the datagridview control option-addcolumn/editcolumn option

Comment: Rebuild your solution, sometimes it solved problems with designer's code.

Answer (score 0):

If you experience problems with the winforms designer, try deleting and newly adding your existing control. Make sure, that you do not change any code in the designer code file unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: I tried that too.Its showing error "column name" is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Have you tried to completly delete the datagridview?

Comment: yeah.I tried both deleting the datagridview completely and also deleting all the columns and adding new.Both gave the same error "column name" is not a valid identifier.

Comment: You can attempt to delete the `DataGridView` and then look in the designer code file for any leftovers which belong to the view. Make sure to backup your code first before editing designer code.

Comment: what could be the possible reason for this error."Column name is not a valid identifier"

Comment: The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e3fdf1f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says this about your issue: 

"This error arises to indicate a code statement that is not valid. Specifically, a field, method, event, or object was improperly named.
To correct this error

    Fix the code to remove the compile errors noted in the error message."

Answer (score 0):

There was a change in visual studio, when form become split into 2 files: `form.cs` and `form.designer.cs`. I still have plenty of single-file forms myself but they are working without issues.

My guess you have done something to the form. To example, new constructor with parameter. Or manually edited `InitializeComponent` method (never do it!). Try to reverse that, if you can, for a time while using designer.

More *clean* would be to simple write down all things you have to do to `DataGridView`, by inspecting `InitializeComponent` method code, then simply add fresh `DataGridView` and do everything again in designer.

Even better solution would be to re-design form from scratch. Refactoring few years old code is good idea, especially if you have issue like this one.

Answer (score 0):

From the forums I have read, this seems to be an existing bug in Visual Studio. I recommend that you manually write out the code in your "Form.Designer.cs". You will have to enter your respective code appropriately and then your column will automatically appear in your DataGridView without the "Column is not a valid identifier" issue that appears when using the Graphical User Interface.

**Form.Designer.cs**

```
#region Component Designer generated code

/// <summary> 
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.YourColumnName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    this.dataGridView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.YourColumnName
    });
    // 
    // YourColumnName
    // 
    this.YourColumnName.HeaderText = "Your Column Name";
    this.YourColumnName.Name = "YourColumnName";
    this.YourColumnName.ReadOnly = true;
    // 
}

#endregion
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn YourColumnName;
```